# In Java, can imported class have same simple-name as importing class? Are there any restrictions?

Tags: java, import, classname

If I have a class names ClassX in package a.b.c, and I want to import the class a.b.x.ClassX

Is there some restriction in Java preventing me from doing so? As far as usage goes, I can always use the fully qualified name of the imported class, right?

Eclipse seems to be unable to resolve this import, I need to know if there is a restriction in Java itself that is causing the problem.

Is the following code legal:

a\b\c\ClassX.java :

```
package a.b.c;
public class ClassX {
//
}
```

a\b\x\ClassX.java :

```
package a.b.x;

import a.b.c.ClassX;

public class ClassX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a.b.c.ClassX newObj = new a.b.c.ClassX();
    }
}
```

If no, then why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be more precise

- it is NOT that we are not allowed to *import* classes with same *simple name* as class importing it,
- but we are not allowed to ***name importing class** same as any class which is already imported*.

Attempting to do so will result in error message: `[NameOfImportingClass] is already defined in this compilation unit`.

Purpose of this restriction is to prevent name ambiguity/clashes.

For example without imports all below is legal:

```
package a;
class B{}

package b;
class B{
   a.B objectPackageaB; //legal - full-package-name so no ambiguity
   b.B objectPackagebB; //legal - full-package-name so no ambiguity
   B objectB; //legal, as now it can only represent B from package "b" -> b.B 
}
```

Now lets add `import a.B`

```
package b;    
import a.B; // <---

class B {
     b.B objectbB;  //still legal, full-package-name so no ambiguity
     a.B objectaB;  //still legal, full-package-name so no ambiguity
     B objectB;   //ambiguous, so ILLEGAL. Which type B should represent? a.B OR b.B?
}
```

IF Java would not prevent such situation, it would need to make decision what type `B objectB` should represent.

We have two options:

1. it would represent `b.B` so type which is *importing*. But that means to use `B` from `a` package we still would need to write it as `a.B`, which means **`import a.B;` is redundant/dead code** which would only be confusing programmers.
2. it would represent `a.B` so type which is *imported*. *But that would feel **unnatural** since inside `class B{ }`, `B` would represent some **other type!***.

Neither of above solutions are good.

**If there is no good solution to a problem, best option is to prevent from appearing.**

Comment: +1, but I'd suggest fleshing out your answer a little, to help novices.

Comment: Hello. I edited your answer trying to clarify that design decision even more. If you don't agree with my edit feel free to roll it back. Just let me know so I would post it as separate answer (which I tried to avoid since your answer is at top and IMO that is the place for answer with most details).

Answer (score 1):

I think no, but instead of `a.b.c.Classx newObj = a.b.c.ClassX()`, write `a.b.c.ClassX newObj = a.b.c.ClassX()` (Class_X_, no Class_x_) and it should work :-)